# one hot encoding classification

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I am having a CSV file like this

```
F1  |  F2  |  F3  |  F4  |  Label
```

I used the `get_dummies` to change the label to a one-hot encoding representation, the data contains 3 different labels, so the file now looks like

```
F1  |  F2  |  F3  |  F4  |  Label1  |  Label2  |  Label3
```

let's say I want to use this data to train a machine learning model. I have to determine the features and label columns
can I set it to:

```py
Features, x = [0:3]
Labels, y = [4:6]
```

Is it right? I am thinking, by doing this way, maybe this could be understood as a multi-label problem since this is not! originally it was a multi-class classification.

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Comment: As I understood, if you make multi-class classification, you can use LabelEncoder instead of OneHotEncoder.

Comment: You don't actually have to one-hot encode the labels. You can do classification with integer labels, where your output is a 3D vector and you take the argmax as the predicted output. But if you do want to use the labels as one-hot, then your approach also works. But your indices are off they should be `x=[:4]` and `y=[4:]`  since the last index is excluded (assuming you want F4 as one of your input features of course).

Comment: @uozcan12 what is the difference between these two?

Comment: @Sean right, that is what I was asking for. if I can use them all as labels in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `iloc` or with `filter`

```py
x = df.iloc[:, :4]
y = df.iloc[:, 4:]

# or

x = df.filter(like='F')
y = df.filter(like='Label')
```

```
print(x)

   F1  F2  F3  F4
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   4

print(y)

  Label1 Label2 Label3
0      x      y      z
1      x      y      z
2      x      y      z
```